# How can I create command that will subtract the data in one table and to other table?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm developing a library system for my project. My adviser ask me to compute a fine for overdue books. What I do is I created one button that will insert data if the user borrow the book and one button for insert data if the user will return. And I have another button for penalty that will insert data if the due date is greater than return date.

This is my code:

```
if (DUEDATE < RETURNDATE)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Penalty (Penalty) VALUES  (@Penalty)";
            SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@Penalty", SqlDbType.Int);
            p1.Value = 50;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

           }
```

This code is not running but this code is my idea.

Comment: Is the question about the SQL or how to get the `DUEDATE` and `RETURNDATE`?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: I do have the command in getting the duedate and returndate because it is on my datetimepicker. What I need to do is to compute a fine if there are overdue books. My idea is duedate subtract to returndate.

Comment: @JonSy are you asking how to calculate a fine based on the duedate and returndate?